# Unset field from an array not working as expected

Tags: post-meta, array

I'm trying to filter a custom options page from acf that is used to create menus based on items that are added on the backoffice, but I'm not being able to unset the fields when they aren't supposed to be shown in the frontend for non logged users.

I've setted the post filtering in the backoffice correctly, as it is working to filter content on the main menu and also when someone tries to access directly the post.

An example of what is in the post_meta field **filtering_profile** field is **uk_user**. For each post it can have multiple pairs of country_profile.

You can see the code below, I'm probably doing some basic mistake but I can't see to figure out where I'm doing it.

```php
foreach ($footer_menu as $k => $column) {
    if ($column['mode'] !== 'menu') {
        continue;
    }
    
    foreach ($column['page_link'] as $key => $link) {
        if (is_array($link['item']) === false) {
            continue;
        }

        $post_id = url_to_postid($link['item']['url']);
        $post_type = get_post_type($post_id);
        
        if ($post_type !== 'post_typeA' && $post_type !== 'post_typeB') {
            continue;
        }
        $post_meta = get_post_meta($post_id, 'filtering_profile');
        if (!isset($post_meta[0]) || get_post_status($post_id) !== 'publish') {
            $link[$key] = false;
        } else if (!in_array($country . "_" . $type, $post_meta[0])) {
            unset($footer_menu[$k]['page_link'][$key]);
        }
    }                   
}
```